# Is it difficult to do high voltage parallel programming using Nick Gammon library?

Tags: arduino-uno, fuses

I have bricked a few AT328P by invalid fuse settings.

Has anybody used the above sketches and the associated circuitry to perform high voltage programming?

Comment: `above sketches`? [these](http://www.gammon.com.au/forum/?id=12898)?

Comment: I've used them, they seem to work fine, otherwise I wouldn't have posted them. What invalid fuse settings anyway? If you changed the clock you can supply an external clock and fix them up. See [bootloader uploader](http://www.gammon.com.au/forum/?id=11635) - the part about an alternate clock source.

Comment: to be honest, I do not recall what I set the fuses to,  but since then, I can upload sketches to the chip, but it will not run the program.

Comment: I have placed the chip in an arduino uno  bored, but it still does not run.  I haven't tried a lower frequency Crystal, could this work?

Comment: Also,   in the reset circuit,   Does the  RC capacitor and  The emitter   Of  Q1  both connect to ground?

Comment: Can you clarify how "I can upload sketches to the chip" and "I have bricked a few AT328P by invalid fuse settings" work together? If it is bricked, you cannot upload sketches to it.

Comment: I suggest you run my [signature detector](http://www.gammon.com.au/forum/?id=11633) sketch using another Arduino, to see if the first one is really bricked, and what the fuse settings are. If you can find out the settings please edit your question and post them.

Comment: Many thanks for your response. I've managed to sort it out, I used http://denki.world3.net/avr_rescue.html to set the fuse back to factory default and now your programmer software recognises it once again, yeepi. However, I am still interested in getting your High-Voltage solution working as it provides cleaner wiring. The only bit I don't fully understand in your reset circuit is does one end of C2 and emitter both go to GND?

Answer (score 1):

I have not tried with those instructions, as I have an AVRDragon, but it's a good exercise for precision, since you have to wire lots of pins.

20+ iirc

My guess is that if anything fails, it's likely to be because of a mistake in the wiring.

If you are planning to do it often, you might consider soldering the wires and the ZIF socket to a prototype board, to preserve your mental sanity.

Comment: +1 for assuming the OP has some mental sanity in the first place.

Comment: Igor Stoppa insomnia